# docker history additional labels

Tags: docker

The question I had is on how can I add a label "author" inside docker history.

What I did was did a docker save as a tar file and on untaring there is a .json file which contains the history label.
inside that I wanted to add for each layer an "author" label.
Also when i do a docker history "tag" command I am not able to see that author label in the columns.
PS: I used json editor to add but I was wondering on how can I add without editing the .json file.
Thanks

Comment: Does the Dockerfile [`LABEL`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#label) directive work?

Comment: no it doesnt , LABEL makes changes to the docker inspect , I want to play with docker history